# Press space bar to continue

Tags: c#

I want the user to press the spacebar to see the next message in my ConsoleApp:

```
Console.WriteLine("a sentence");

//press space to see next sentence
       
Console.WriteLine("another sentence");

//press space to see next sentence
      
Console.WriteLine("etc");
```

If possible the user should not visualize any prompt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop reading characters until space:

```
Console.WriteLine("a sentence");
while (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar != ' ') ;
       
Console.WriteLine("another sentence");
while (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar != ' ') ;
      
Console.WriteLine("etc");
```

Alternatively you can create a method that comprises the `while` statement and call it instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;

namespace DemoApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void WaitForSpace()
        {
            while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar) ;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a sentence");
            WaitForSpace();
            Console.WriteLine("another sentence");
            WaitForSpace();
            Console.WriteLine("etc");
            WaitForSpace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("a sentence");
if(Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
{
      Console.WriteLine("another sentence");
      if(Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
      {
           Console.WriteLine("etc");
      }
}
```

Comment: I think that this code lacks readability if I'll be writing a lot of sentences, but I upvoted for the effort and you gave me another point of view!